# Is there a better way to get a possibly-empty array slice/range from some index to the end?

Tags: arrays, slice, fish

In fish array ranges are one-based and inclusive of both extremes, which, [unsurprisingly](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html), leads to problems when possibly-zero-length-ranges are required.

In particular, I'm in a situation where I split out the first arguments for my own consumption, and I want to forward the rest of them - which may be none! - to some command. If this was Python, I could do something like:

```
my_arg = sys.argv[1]
other_args = sys.argv[2:]
```

However, the straight translation of this to fish unfortunately doesn't work in edge cases; consider

```
set -l my_arg $argv[1]
set -l other_args $argv[2..-1]
```

(I kept the same indexes as, while in fish indexing is 1-based, `$argv` doesn't include what would be `sys.argv[0]`)

This works fine as long as there are enough arguments; for example, if I invoke my command with arguments `a b c d e` I'll get `$my_arg = a` and `$other_args = b c d e`.

However, if I invoke it with just `a`, `other_args` will be surprisingly set to `a` as well. This comes from the fact that `-1` actually gets expanded to something to the effect of `(count $argv)`, so the statement above is equivalent to

```
set -l other_args $argv[2..1]
```

which is an inverted range from the nonexistent element 2 to the existent element 1, *inclusive*, which boils down to plain `$argv[1]`.

To avoid this problem, currently I'm using this horrible workaround

```
set -l other_args $argv[2..(expr (count $argv) + 1)]
```

which ensures that the last index is *one past* the last, forcing the range to be a "straight" one, albeit possibly fully out of range (which returns an empty list as required).

However, I'm wondering: is there a better solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I'm wondering: is there a better solution that I'm missing?

Upgrade to 3.0. This was a bug in 2.7 that is fixed there.

The way this works now is that, if only one of the indices in a range is negative, it'll always be interpreted as the larger of the two, so with a negative end, iteration is forced to go forward.

If the index isn't actually larger, this results in no elements instead, which is precisely what you want here.

Comment: That's great! Unfortunately I'm not sure I'll be able to upgrade to fish 3 on all the machines where this script is used, so for the moment I'll have to keep the workaround, however it's nice to know it has been fixed.

Comment: An alternative workaround is to check if argv has 2 elements before using it: `set -q argv[2]; and set -l other_args $argv[2..-1]`

Comment: Eh I think it's worse, as you have to repeat twice the starting index (so it's easier for it to get out of sync). I'll just keep the `expr` kludge.

Comment: The `expr` kludge starts an external process, and will only work on fish >=2.7 (because that was the first release to allow invalid indices). Checking works on fish back to at least 2.2.0.

Comment: Starting an external process in this particular case isn't much of a problem, but some more past compatibility is welcome; I'll adopt your solution.